# Can I get the result directly when SqlDependency fires?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldependency

I have set up a dependency as follows. I get a call back whenever a new row is added.

But when I get call back, I then need to run a similar query to get the appropriate rows.

Is it possible to get the result of this dependency query sent with the callback?

```
    public void InitialiseDependencyForFills()
    {

        string cmdText = "SELECT [Symbol] FROM [Jug].[Orders] WHERE [AccountIdent] = 'Jack' and [Status] = 'NEW'";
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
        {

            SqlDependency FilledDependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            FilledDependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyForFillsChange);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // Process the DataReader.
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Short answer: no. Query notifications inherently detect only that results have changed, not what the results are. You could, of course, write your own wrapper class around `SqlDependency` that augments the event by executing the command and passing along the result (in a `DataTable` or suchlike).

Comment: But it would still mean running the query again after the notification. I am trying to reduce the time to get the results. I was hoping that as sql server is effectively running the query on any changes to the table - it might pass out the results...

Comment: The engine may not run the query at all, or anything resembling it. Per the [docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms188323): "When the server is heavily loaded, SQL Server may produce a query notification message for the subscription rather than performing the work of determining whether the results of the query have changed." It would also be extremely inefficient to always include actual results -- imagine that happening for a notification of the form `SELECT * FROM HugeTable`.

Comment: Understood. Pity

Comment: If you want faster results, nothing prevents you from constructing your own query notification mechanism. See ["Alternatives to Query Notifications"](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms187528). Set up an `INSERT` trigger that sends a message to a Service Broker queue (that can include the actual row data). Set up a `RECEIVE` from this queue in the background. This has a bit of a learning curve, though, especially if you're totally unfamiliar with Service Broker. Only do this if you really need those reduced response times. Or consider out-of-band notifications (not SQL based).